# How to access array that has two objects but doesn't accept bracket or dot notation?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm using Promise.all() for the first time, hopefully, this isn't too ignorant...

I'm unable to access my array with dot notation or bracket notation. I have two objects in the array, each with a key of 0 and then 1.

I get undefined when I try using indices and bracket notation.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4dNm.jpg) of it all...

I'm using Promise.all() for the first time, hopefully, this isn't too ignorant...

```
    // GET ALL POKEMON NAMES
    let fetchAll = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/? 
   limit=20&offset=0`);
    let fetchEach = fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1");

    let dataArr = []

    Promise.all([fetchAll, fetchEach])
        .then(files => files.forEach(file => process(file.json())))
        .then(console.log(dataArr[1].abilities))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    let process = (prom) => {
        prom.then(data => dataArr.push(data))
    }
```

I expect to be able to grab the object in the array but only get undefined.

Comment: Your `process` isn't returning anything, so it's disconnected from the outer Promise chain. That's quite convoluted anyway, consider having a function that `fetch`es a URL and returns its `.json()`. Then: `Promise.all([getResp('? 
   limit=20&offset=0'), getResp('1')]).then((dataArr) => /* use dataArr here */ })`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, my way didn't seem like the most optimal way to go about it. Whats the '1'  in the getResp referring to? Is that first object key a string?

Comment: That's the last part of the URL you're fetching (a bit like your `fetchEach` variable, but less repetitive)